# How to run pynput in the background?

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard, terminate, pynput

I am using pynput's `keyboard.Listener` and have joined the thread.

```py
def main():
    with Listener(on_release=checkSPress) as listener:
        listener.join() # keep on listening

def checkSPress(key):
    if 'char' in dir(key):
        if key.char == 's':
            print("Starting ...")

main()
```

After the `s` key is pressed I want it to terminate the listener and run things in the main thread. I want to this because after the `s` key is pressed I create a GUI but it throws an error that the `QApplication must be created inside main thread`. Is there a way I can go back to the main thread and run the function or terminate the listener entirely (I'm fairly new to threading and pynput.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `return False` from `callback` to stop `Listner`. Just try:

```
if key.char == 's':
    print("Starting ...")
    return False
```